# Не считывает кол-во рефералов

Tags: sqlite, telegram, aiogram, бот, sqlite3

Должно при открытии профиля, считываться кол-во рефералов данного пользователя, в итоге, все время считывает 0.
Код main файла:

```
if message.text == 'Профиль':
    print(db.count_referalls(message.from_user.id))
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваш Айди: {0.id}\nВаше Имя: {0.first_name}\nВаш Юзернейм: @{0.username}\n------------\nВаша реферальная ссылка: https://t.me/{1}?start={0.id}\nКол-во рефералов: {2}'.format(message.from_user, config.BOT_NAME, db.count_referalls(message.from_user.id)), parse_mode='HTML')
```

Код Базы данных:

```
def count_referalls(id):
    with connection:
        return cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'referer_id'=?", (id,)).fetchone()[0]
```

Табличный вид базы данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно понимаю в чем проблема, но не понимаю, как ее исправить, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Предполагаю, `id` в функции у вас это ссылка на экземпляр объекта

Comment: А вы можете показать объект `db` подробнее? Измените текст вопроса, добавив код